# Controlling multiple children ViewControllers through one 'root' ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm creating an app that has a root view controller. This root view controller is the parent of many other children view controllers which are major states in the app.

Since I'm adding the children to the root all at the start of the root's `viewDidLoad`, all of the children's viewDid and viewWill methods fire when added to the root rather than when I choose to show the child view controller.

Does anyone know a good way to stave off the viewDid or viewWill methods of the children until needed? If not, is there a way to have some control over these children view controllers? Please and thank you!

Root view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let storyboard = storyboard else {
        print("ERROR: No storyboard found! Early return")
        return
    }

    // Introduction
    let introVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IntroID") as! IntroductionViewController
    self.configureChildViewController(childController: introVC, onView: self.view)

    // Login
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginID") as! LoginViewController
    self.configureChildViewController(childController: loginVC, onView: self.view)

    // Move to the first VC
    self.goToVC(childVC: introVC)
}
```

Moving to a new child view controller

```
func goToVC(childVC: UIViewController) {

    // Bring child to front
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: childVC.view)

    // Create the moveTo animations to the VC
    childVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Configuration of child classes

```
extension UIViewController {
func configureChildViewController(childController: UIViewController, onView: UIView) {

    if let view = childController.view {

        // Add the view controller
        addChildViewController(childController)

        // Add and resize the subview
        onView.addSubview(view)
        constrainViewEqual(holderView: onView, view: view)
    } else {
        print("ERROR: The child controller has no usable view")
    }
}

func constrainViewEqual(holderView: UIView, view: UIView) {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // Create the view's new constraints
    let pinTop    = self.createConstraint(ofType: .top,    inView: holderView, newView: view)
    let pinBottom = self.createConstraint(ofType: .bottom, inView: holderView, newView: view)
    let pinLeft   = self.createConstraint(ofType: .left,   inView: holderView, newView: view)
    let pinRight  = self.createConstraint(ofType: .right,  inView: holderView, newView: view)

    // Add the constraints
    holderView.addConstraints([pinTop, pinBottom, pinLeft, pinRight])
}

private func createConstraint(ofType: NSLayoutAttribute, inView: UIView, newView: UIView) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    return NSLayoutConstraint( item:       newView,
                               attribute:  ofType,
                               relatedBy:  .equal,
                               toItem:     inView,
                               attribute:  ofType,
                               multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant:   0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give you is to not add all the children to the parent view controller at once. Maintain at most one child view controller at a time.

```
func goToVC(childVC: UIViewController) {
    if childViewControllers.count == 0 {

        self.addChildViewController(childVC)
        childVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        self.containerView.addSubview(childVC.view)
        childVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    } else {

        let oldViewController = self.childViewControllers[0]
        childVC.view.frame = oldViewController.view.frame
        oldViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(childVC)
        self.transition(from: oldViewController, to: childVC, duration: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil) { completed in
            oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            childVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```